# Stacked Widgets trigger both their own event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem using binding on event handlers.

I have two stacked frames positionned on a mainFrame. Each frame has its own button. When I click on one button, the associated frame is lifted.

On each frame, I have one listbox. These listboxes are at the same position on the mainFrame. When I select one item in the first listbox, it fills the other listbox with new content. Then I click the second frame button to access my second listbox. I duplicated (with new names) the event to do the exact same thing with my second listbox to fill a third listbox.

However, when I select one item in my second listbox, it appears that the first listbox's event is also triggered but only one time (if I redo my selection it only triggers the second listbox's event).

EDIT : I put a "short" version of my code as requested.

When I select db1 or db2 it the first listbox, the frame2 is lifted and *test2* is printed. Then I select item1 or item2 and both *test2/test1* are printed instead of only *test1*

```
from tkinter import *

class Page(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):

    def dbCheckCommand(self, event, page2):
        page2.collections.delete(0, END)
        print("test2")
        page2.collections.insert(END, "item1")
        page2.collections.insert(END, "item2")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.databases = Listbox(self, height=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.databases.insert(END, "db1")
        self.databases.insert(END, "db2")
        self.databases.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.colls = []
        self.collections = Listbox(self, height=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.collections.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

class MainView(Frame):

    def on_p1_listbox_selection(self, event, page1, page2):
        page1.dbCheckCommand(event, page2)
        page2.lift()

    def on_p2_listbox_selection(self, event):
        print("test1")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=5)
        buttonframe = Frame(self)
        container = Frame(self)
        buttonframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

        container.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        p1 = Page1(container)
        p2 = Page2(container)

        p1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
        p2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")


        b1 = Button(buttonframe, text="1 - Server & Database", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = Button(buttonframe, text="2 - Collection", command=p2.lift)

        b1.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        b2.pack(fill="both", expand=1)


        p1.databases.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event: self.on_p1_listbox_selection(event, p1, p2))
        p2.collections.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event: self.on_p2_listbox_selection(event))

        p1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    root.wm_geometry("1100x500")
    root.wm_title("MongoDB Timed Sample Generator")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. NOT your whole code with "too much dependencies". Create a new, _minimal_ program that illustrates your problem. It sounds like you only need two frames, two listboxes, two buttons, and another dozen of so lines of code to tie it all together.

Comment: When you write *"I don't post any code here because their are too much dependences"* it's can be interpreted as *"I don't interested in my question at all"*, no offence. Even a long code is better, of course you will got stomped by downvotes, but if question is interesting - someone could crawl your problem (never rely on that). As is your question can provide no answers, but assumptions only, which unverifable. Take a look on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593) and try to cut all dependencies. Good luck!

Comment: @BryanOakley  I hope the code I added won't be too long

Comment: @Clément That is a much better question with the code you added. From a quick glance it does appear to be a MCVE example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<ListboxSelect>>` event fires whenever the selection changes. That means both when a new selection is made, or the current selection is de-selected.

By default the selected item in a listbox will be exported to the [X selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection). Since there can always only be one *X selection*, when you select an item in one listbox, any other listboxes will be deselected. Thus, when you click on an item in the second listbox, the selection of the first listbox will be lost, and causing the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event to be sent.

A simple solution is to turn off this behavior in your listboxes, so that you can have something selected in each listbox simultaneously. You do this by setting the `exportselection` flag to `False` in each listbox.

For example:

```
self.databases = Listbox(..., exportselection=False)
...
self.collections = Listbox(..., exportselection=False)
```